# PHP Prophecy mocking not existing class

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, mockery, prophecy

I'm writing a package that I would like to write tests in [Prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy) instead of [Mockery](https://github.com/mockery/mockery). The package class `Bar` has a method `sayName` that requires an object implementing `FooInterface` as a parameter.

with Mockery there is no problem for creating a mock of non existing class:

```
<?php
use \Prophecy\Prophet;
use \Mockery;

class Bar 
{
    public function sayName(\FooInterface $foo)
    {
        echo $foo->test();
    }
}

$mock = Mockery::mock('Foo', 'FooInterface');
$mock->shouldReceive('test')->times(1)->andReturn('This is a mock test');

$bar = new Bar();
$bar->sayName($mock);
```

gives:

> This is a mock test

How to achieve the same with [Prophecy](https://github.com/phpspec/prophecy)?